# How to promote my opencart store to google?

Tags: seo, opencart2.x, search-and-promote

I have used opencart ecommerce cms for my store and now i want to promote it into google that appears in google search.

I need total seo guide and how long it takes to display in google search.

Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can follow the below links for more details

http://docs.opencart.com/administration/seo/

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=feature/blog/info&blog_id=86

Comment: Ok i got it ! Can you say normally how many days or hours google takes to list in google search ?

Comment: I have a project and it should be listed on google search by product !

Comment: regarding ranking, it's hard to estimate timeline, it can take upto month

Comment: Is there any supportive extension like (yoast plugin for wordpress) ?